# How to visualize an audio file in an android app using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to visualize an file  in android.I am using the following library to do it `com.chibde:audiovisualizer:2.1.0`. But my app crashes saying

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
>                                                                                 at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer

I have written this code by reading this blog https://mindorks.com/android/store/Equalizers-and-Visualizations/gautamchibde/android-audio-visualizer.

The following is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton playPauseBtn;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playPauseBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_play_pause);
        setPlayer();
    }
    public void playPause(View view){
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playPauseBtn.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_play_red_48dp));
            }
            else
            {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                playPauseBtn.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_pause_red_48dp));
            }
        }
    }

    public void setPlayer(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setPlayer: setPlayer() called");
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.normal);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: init() called");
        LineVisualizer lineVisualizer = findViewById(R.id.lineVisualizer);
        // set custom color to the line.
        lineVisualizer.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.custom));
        // set the line with for the visualizer between 1-10 default 1.
        lineVisualizer.setStrokeWidth(1);
        // Set you media player to the visualizer.
        lineVisualizer.setPlayer(mediaPlayer);
    }
}
```

//The following is my ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.techmate.asifa.waves.MainActivity">

   <com.chibde.visualizer.LineVisualizer
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:id="@+id/lineVisualizer"/>


    <include layout="@layout/layout_audio_buttons"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the following is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techmate.asifa.waves"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.chibde:audiovisualizer:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My app crashes when i run it and the following error is shown in my logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:218)
    at com.chibde.BaseVisualizer.setPlayer(BaseVisualizer.java:81)
    at com.chibde.BaseVisualizer.setPlayer(BaseVisualizer.java:77)
    at com.techmate.asifa.waves.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:81)
    at com.techmate.asifa.waves.MainActivity.setPlayer(MainActivity.java:66)
    at com.techmate.asifa.waves.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

Comment: Looks like you are not setting an audio session

Comment: The audio gets played when i comment out The SoundVisualtion library.@Tase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this, it appeared that you were not supplying audio session ID to the visualizer.

```
 public void init(){
    Log.d(TAG, "init: init() called");
    LineVisualizer lineVisualizer = findViewById(R.id.lineVisualizer);
    // set custom color to the line.
    lineVisualizer.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.custom));
    // set the line with for the visualizer between 1-10 default 1.
    lineVisualizer.setStrokeWidth(1);
    // Set you media player to the visualizer.
    lineVisualizer.setPlayer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());  //Added session ID
}
```

Comment: After I reinstalled the app it worked.Thanks Taseer Ahmad

Comment: Also, check if you have added the RECORD_AUDIO permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can add RECORD_AUDIO permissions inside your method:

```
 if (context?.let {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        it,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    )
} != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
activity?.let {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        it,
        Array(1) { Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO },
        0
    )
}
```

if (mediaPlayer!!.audioSessionId != -1)